# Predicting images Jupyter notebook

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

For my first Machine Learning experience i have a basic classification to do.

I have 3 different folders :

```
train_path = './dataset/pneumonia/train/'
test_path = './dataset/pneumonia/test/'
val_path = './dataset/pneumonia/val/
```

each folders :

```
os.listdir(train_path)
```

returns

```
['NORMAL', 'PNEUMONIA']
```

In each sets :

- Training set:

  - Normal:  949
  - Pneumonia:  949
- Test set:

  - Normal:  317
  - Pneumonia:  317
- Validation set:

  - Normal:  317
  - Pneumonia:  317

I use tensorflow :

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
image_gen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=10,        # rotate the image 10 degrees
    width_shift_range=0.10,   # Shift the pic width by a max of 5%
    height_shift_range=0.10,  # Shift the pic height by a max of 5%
    rescale=1/255,            # Rescale the image by normalzing it.
    shear_range=0.1,          # Shear means cutting away part of the image (max 10%)
    zoom_range=0.1,           # Zoom in by 10% max
    horizontal_flip=True,     # Allow horizontal flipping
    fill_mode='nearest'       # Fill in missing pixels with the nearest filled value
)


image_gen.flow_from_directory(train_path)
image_gen.flow_from_directory(test_path)
```

I create a model (basic model) :

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(image_width, image_height, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape=(image_width, image_height, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), input_shape=(image_width, image_height, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), input_shape=(image_width, image_height, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), input_shape=(image_width, image_height, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))

# Dropouts help reduce overfitting by randomly turning neurons off during training.
# Here we say randomly turn off 50% of neurons.
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

# Last layer, remember its binary so we use sigmoid
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Then I train it :

```
train_image_gen = image_gen.flow_from_directory(
    train_path,
    target_size=image_shape[:2],
    color_mode='rgb',
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary'
)

results = model.fit_generator(train_image_gen,epochs=20,
                              validation_data=test_image_gen,
                             callbacks=[early_stop, board])
```

So far so good results are correct :

```
pred_probabilities = model.predict_generator(test_image_gen)
predictions = pred_probabilities > 0.5
confusion_matrix(test_image_gen.classes,predictions)
```

I obtain rather good results :

[image] [image]

My issue is when I want to predict images it returns results which are far from being correct:

```
val_image_gen = image_gen.flow_from_directory(
    val_path,
    target_size=image_shape[:2],
    color_mode='rgb',
    class_mode='binary',
)

pred_probabilities = model.predict_generator(val_image_gen)
predictions = pred_probabilities > 0.5
```

Here are some output I obtain :

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.51      0.57      0.53       317
           1       0.51      0.44      0.47       317

    accuracy                           0.51       634
   macro avg       0.51      0.51      0.50       634
weighted avg       0.51      0.51      0.50       634
```

THe confusion matrix on this data set is the following :

```
[[180 137]
 [176 141]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A few issues with your code:

- You are using test set for validation and validation set for testing.
  This may be a problem or not, depending on your data and how it was
  split.
- Augmentation should be applied only to training set. Use    separate
  instance of `ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)` for testing    and
  validation.

Your test results look like they were got from untrained model. Check if the `model` object you are running test on is the same one you were training. You may want to use `model.save()` and `load_model()` functions to preserve model weights after training.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced :

```
val_image_gen = image_gen.flow_from_directory(
    val_path,
    target_size=image_shape[:2],
    color_mode='rgb',
    class_mode='binary',
)
```

by:

```
val_image_gen = image_gen.flow_from_directory(
    val_path,
    target_size=image_shape[:2],
    color_mode='rgb',
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary',
    shuffle=False
)
```

I obtain nice results :

[[**269**  48]

[  3 **314**]]